# Where does cs-cart set the sort parameter in the frontend search?

Tags: php, cs-cart

In CS-Cart version 4.8.2.SP2 I'm trying to edit what parameter the frontend general search sorts by. I'm trying to find where in the code this is set so I can find what hook to use and what format it needs to be.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the function `fn_search`, it should contain all the necessary information;

The hook you probably want to use is: `additional_fields_in_search`.

In the hookbase (https://helpdesk.cs-cart.com/api) it is prototyped as follows:

```
Executed for each part of a search query; it allows to modify the SQL conditions of the search
$params     array     List of parameters passed to fn_get_products functions
$fields     array     List of fields for retrieving
$sortings   array     Sorting fields
$condition  string    String containing SQL-query condition possibly prepended with a logical operator (AND or OR)
$join       string    String with the complete JOIN information (JOIN type, tables and fields) for an SQL-query
$sorting    string    String containing the SQL-query ORDER BY clause. This variable isn't used; it remains only for backward compatibility.
$group_by   string    String containing the SQL-query GROUP BY field. This variable isn't used; it remains only for backward compatibility.
$tmp        string    String containing SQL-query search condition by piece
$piece      string    Part of the search query
$having     array     HAVING condition
```